# Group Policy for Office 2013 Home and Business

Tags: group-policy, microsoft-office-2013

On our network we have Office 2013 Group Policy settings, but users that have Office 2013 Home and Business installed are not seeing these settings.  I have checked the RSOP.MSC, and the settings are applied to the pc, but Office is not inheriting the changes.
Users that have 2013 Standard or Professional installed do not have this issue.

Was Group Policy eliminated from certain editions of office in 2013?

I've searched the web, but I don't see anyone talking about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only Office 2013 Standard and Professional Plus support Group Policy.
Home & Student, Home & Business, and Professional do not.

In Office 365, ProPlus is the only edition that supports Group Policy.
The Home Premium, Small Business, and Small Business Premium plans do not.